# Is there anything like 3.5's Aptitude weapon property in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, weapons

> A wielder who has feats that affect the use of a particular type of
>   weapon, such as Weapon Focus, Greater Weapon Focus, Weapon
>   Specialization, or the like, can apply the benefits of those feats to
>   any weapon that has the aptitude quality. In addition, if any of the
>   wielder's weapons use feats are specifically keyed to the aptitude
>   weapon's type he gains a +1 bonus on attack and damage rolls. --[Tome of Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tome_of_Battle:_The_Book_of_Nine_Swords)

Is there anything in pathfinder that has a similar effect to the 3.5 Aptitude weapon property in that you're able to apply weapon specific feats to other weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**

The [Martial Mastery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/martial-mastery-combat-human) feat allows you to apply weapon-specific feats to entire groups of similar weapons.

> **Prerequisites:** Martial Versatility, fighter level 16th, human.
>
> **Benefit:** Each combat feat you have that applies to a specific weapon
>   (e.g., Weapon Focus) can be used with all weapons in the same weapon
>   group.

A non-exhaustive list of weapon groups can be found under the Fighter's [Weapon Training](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Weapon-Training-Ex-) ability and is reproduced below. Note that some weapons appear in multiple groups and that *"GMs may add other weapons to these groups, or add entirely new groups."*

- Axes
- Blades, Heavy
- Blades, Light
- Bows
- Close
- Crossbows
- Double
- Firearms
- Flails
- Hammers
- Monk
- Natural
- Polearms
- Siege engines
- Spears
- Thrown

Answer (score -1):

There are some feats related to fighter weapon groups, which is similar to what you are looking for. Some require fighter levels but not all. Here are two I found that don't require fighter levels:

> **Martial Focus (Combat)**
>
> Choose one fighter weapon group. While wielding a weapon from this group with which you are proficient, you gain a +1 bonus on damage rolls.
>
> *Weapon Master’s Handbook*

and...

> **Defensive Weapon Training (Combat)**
>
> Choose a weapon group from the fighter's weapon training class ability list (except natural weapons). You gain a +2 dodge bonus on AC when an opponent attacks you using a weapon from that group. If you also have the weapon training class feature in the selected group, your dodge bonus from this feat increases to +3.
>
> *Ultimate Combat*

For reference, fighter weapon groups are groups of thematically related weapons (axes, flails, thrown, etc.), defined in the Weapon Training ability of the Fighter class.